# How do I fetch an array from a Vue lifecycle hook function that gets data from firebase / firestore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

On my View List page where the user selects a list and is forwarded to a page with all the items on the list.

the List is a firebase collection, and each list has an array of item IDs. I want to for each loop through the Item collection with these Item IDs, set them to a variable, and then use it in the component.

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="card card-body mt-4">
    <h3> {{ list.name }} </h3>
    <a> {{ items }} </a>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Logic**

```
<script>
import { listRef } from '@/firebase'

export default {
  name: 'ListView',
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      list: null,
      items: null
    }
  },
  created() {
      listRef.doc(this.id).get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.list = doc.data();
          console.log(this.list)
        } else {
          console.log("No such list");
        }
      }),
```

**This is where I'm confused.** I'm not able to grab the list.product_ids, reference it in this function, loop through the item collection to find all the matches, then set those items into an array.

```
      this.list_IDs.forEach(id in
      itemRef.document(id).getDocument(snapshot => {
          let items = snapshot.data()
          console.log(items)
        }))
  }
}
```

**JSON response**

```
[[Target]]: Object
id: "6LvlxBcUL"
name: "Picnic"
list_ids: Array(3)
0: "J1FAa1D9C2QIDgi"
1: "JHqzvkAB9SZcAil"
2: "Kse5FPfakpYOjiU"
```

Comment: Can you add the json data that your getting as response ?

Comment: @Amaarrockz I'm getting the correct response data for my list, which is the list name, list id, and array of item IDs. I'm not sure how to grab this item array and immediately use it in a 2nd function. do you know if it'd need a separate hook?

Comment: Also add the complete code of the function where your confused and also the place where you are invoking the function. Remember bits and pieces wont help

Comment: @Amaarrockz hmm everything is there. the code I need & am unsure on how to implement is in the markdown box above the json. can my 2nd function use the value generated by that first function in the same created() function,or will it need a different hook?